# established in or over

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following passage from Meredith's [*Diana of the Crossways*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4u0XAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA46&dq=%22shall+have+been+firmly+established+in+or+over%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwvI3iqMjSAhXFr1QKHVPxDQgQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22shall%20have%20been%20firmly%20established%20in%20or%20over%22&f=false), Sir Lukin, who tried to seduce the heroine and who has to keep that episode in secret from his wife, is remorseful.

> Reflection washed him clean. Secresy is not a medical restorative, by no means a good thing for the baffled amorously-adventurous cavalier, unless the lady's character shall have been firmly **established in or over** his hazy wagging noddle. Reflection informed him that the honourable, generous, proud girl spared him for the sake of the house she loved.

My question is: what does the expression "in or over" mean here? Is there any opposition between "establish in" and "establish over" which is referred to? My reading of it is that "her character shall dominate/usurp his mind", but perhaps I am wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The way I read it, "establish in" means the lady's character would find a permanent place (kind of set up shop) within his mind; "established over" would mean the lady's character would dominate his mind. The definition of "over" as "the possession of authority, power of jurisdiction in regard to some thing or person," would apply here. However, because it's partially a comic passage, the author might have been going for something lighter than that: her character like a little dark cloud over his head.